# Scala: Adding native types to type parameter list throws an error

Tags: scala

When defining type parameter lists in Scala functions, it introduces type variables that can be referenced in signature of the function, e.g.

```
def test[A,B,C] (a: A, f: (A,B) => C): B => C
```

My question may be trivial, but I can not seem to figure out why

```
def sum[Int](l: List[Int]): Int = { 
    l.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a +b ) 
}
```

Throws

```
None of the overloaded alternatives of method + in class Int with types
 (x: Double): Double
 (x: Float): Float
 (x: Long): Long
 (x: Int): Int
 (x: Char): Int
 (x: Short): Int
 (x: Byte): Int
 (x: String): String
match arguments ((b : Int))mdoc
```

Whereas simply removing the type parameter [Int] compiles completely fine.

```
def sum(l:List[Int]): Int = { 
    l.foldLeft(0)((x, y) => x + y)
}
```

Comment: `def sum[Int]` you are creating a new type parameter called `Int` which shadows the original type `Int`, you can just replace that name with just `A` and the code should be the same and a generic type `A` doesn't have a `+` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sum[Int](l: List[Int]): Int` method definition you are actually declaring a [generic type parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) called `Int` which just matches the name of predefined type but is not related to it so compiler fails to find a valid `+` method.

Comment: Aha! I see! So no using native types in type parameter lists! I will flag your answer as correct ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: @JOKKINATOR yes, you should avoid using existing type names as generic type parameters in method definition. Though in this case you simply do not need a generic type parameter (as you have done in `def sum(l:List[Int]): Int` yourself)